# Disable Control Print (Ctrl + P) in Pdf Viewer Devexpress Winform

Tags: c#, devexpress, pdf-viewer

I want to protect PDF in `PdfViewer` DevExpress, prevent user to print, save as and user just may to view only. I have created simple project and run well, but when user press <kbd>Ctrl + P</kbd>, user still can print that file. Any suggest to solve this?

This the image that I attach, and I don't want user show this and when user press <kbd>Ctrl + P</kbd> they will look that this document PDF is protected:

[image: Print]

I try this code in `Key_Down` event of `PdfViewer`:

```
private void pdfViewer1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.P) //detect key ctrl+p
    {
        e.Handled = false;
        MessageBox.Show("This Document is Protected !", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        return;
    }
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: `if ((e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C) || (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A))
    {` you mean this?

Comment: @MichaelMao so sorry, i have updated my explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent your `PdfViewer` from recieving <kbd>Ctrl + P</kbd> then you must use [`KeyEventArgs.SuppressKeyPress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress(v=vs.110).aspx) property.
Here is example:

```
private void pdfViewer1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.P) //detect key ctrl+p
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true; //<= Set it to true.
        MessageBox.Show("This Document is Protected !", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        return;
    }        
}
```

Comment: your suggest code above isn't work,.. i have tested it and print dialog still show when pressing ctrl+p... any other way?

Comment: @aminvincent I have tested it too. And it works on my side. It seems that `Ctrl + P` is handled by another control in your form. For example, there are can be `Ribbon` or `Panel` with `Print` button on it. If so, you need to remove `Print` button from it.

Comment: exactly i read pdf file from blob data oracle and read it using `MemoryStream` . i have remove my button print, open, and save as from my ribbon panel. i tested again and it's not working. perhaps this is because of `MemoryStream`?

Comment: yes,..you're right... i have solve this by using your suggest code above,..finally i delete all item that contain print, save, etc that i don't need...many thanks